# Flutter : Understading Widget,Element and Render tree

Tags: flutter, rendering

I have been trying to understand Flutter and How rendering works under the hood. I have watched a video regarding "How flutter renders a widget?" [How Flutter Rendering works?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996ZgFRENMs&t=847s) I got to know that there are 3 (Widget, Element and Render Tree) trees being built. In the Video Widget is the blueprint of the layout, Element is the configuration and Render Tree does the actual paining. I am still not been able to understand as in the video, Matt Sulliman says about these three as follows :

1. Widget : Immutable Description of UI (Means It won't change?), also It describe configuration of Element.
2. Element : Instantiation of the widget in a widget tree at particular location. (BuildContext?)
3. Render : handles size, painting and other low level stuff.

My main concern is that at 6:36 of the video, Matt sulliman says that Element represents actual piece of the UI. **This part is quite confusing to me. Because if Elements are configuration as per the analogy of Configuration, Lifecycle and paint. So Render Tree should be the UI part. I didn't get that part.**

[image: rendering of the widget (confusion starts here)]

Is there any analogy or simple way by which I can understand what's the responsibility of each tree?

Comment: have you read [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-layer-cake-widgets-elements-renderobjects-7644c3142401)?

Comment: @pskink, I have read the Medium article shared, I got insights, can you clear out my doubt about responsibility of each trees? so from the article I understood that Widget tree is just an blueprint, Element tree does the comparison and Render Tree does the actual rendering. Let me know if anything required or I am wrong. Also If it's true that elements do the comparison only, then from the image that I have uploaded, why it's written that elements represents actual piece of UI??

Comment: yes, this is what you say, but unfortunately i hahe no idea what they mean by "elements represents actual piece of UI"...

Comment: @pskink, can you see my comment and tell me what I understand is correct or not? about 3 trees.

Comment: yes, it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is right from the engineering interviews that the Flutter team often gives.

The Element Tree(Widget Tree) and the Render Tree are the way to have both data flows reactive and be able to interface back with the OOP classes.

Element Tree gets rebuilt all the time to than help the Render Tree figure out what to prune and add to the Render tree for each frame produced.

The reason why Google engineers call the element tree the widget tree as each widget is stored as a configuration of each Element class in the tree.

Think of this way
Element Tree tells widget configuration
Render Tree is the changes and update

So how is it reactive as we still need an observer, right?

State Class is the observer back to the OOP classes in the dev code of the app.

The whole reason there are not child node APIs is so that each Tree could be an API layer to access at the OOP widget class level in forms of
BuildContext--Elements in Element Tree
RenderObject--Render Tree
State---Observer of Render Tree output
Key-Elements in Element Tree

AND, tree is math thing with Google Engineers and refers to specific graph structures both the Widget Tree(Element Tree) and Render Trees form in that its a real math tree which also means we only have DAG edges and no completed cycles among the edges.